# Express Javascript Regex to only allow strings without periods

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express, routes

I have an express route that handles localhost:3000/test. I want everything after this that doesn't have a period to render with the same router.get command. I'm struggling to figure out the correct Javascript regex string.

```
router.get('/test/:path[\s^.]*$', function () {
    //res.render etc
}
```

So, when I visit localhost:3000/test/math or localhost:3000/test/math/geometry I want it to use the same route. But when I navigate to localhost:3000/test/math/geometry.test I want it to use a different route. I have used regex before just not sure how to combine it with the express params functionality.

EDIT: adeneo's idea will not work since I cannot chain my functions correctly using a check for a period. This is the point of regex, so that I check the url before I do the page logic.

Raul I'm afraid you have misunderstood the question. Let me try to state it more clearly.

I have a list of folders like this:

```
test
--folder1
----test1.js
----test2.js
----test3.js
--folder2
----folder2-1
----folder2-3
------test4.js
------test5.js
----test6.js
--folder3
```

The following urls should have one regex expression that captures them:

```
test/folder1
test/folder2
test/folder2/folder2-3
```

and another that only catches the following:

```
test/folder1/test1.js
test/folder2/folder2-3/test4.js
test/folder2/test6.js
```

Like I said, I have done regex, I just cannot figure out how to use the :paramName functionality of Express with it.

Comment: Don't periods need to be escaped in regexes? The carat may need to be inside a character class, not sure though; it's s special character meaning beginning of line.

Comment: You can't really add a regular expression in the string, either you use a regex as the route, or you use a string

Comment: The easiest would probably be to check the url for a period inside the route, and just call `next()`

Comment: adeneo that is a great point. I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order does matter in this case.
If you put first the exceptions yo will handled the path.

```
app.get('/test/math/geometry.test', function (req, res) {
  res.send('catch it');
});

app.get('/test/:path*', function (req, res) {
  res.send('the params are    ' +  JSON.stringify(req.params));
});
```

If you try this routes with for example ´/test/maths/dificults´ you can see in the end that req.params have something like:

```
 {"0":"/maths/dificults","path":"maths"}
```

You can access to the raw param by position, in this case '0' because by name you have the params cut in the first '/'

**EDIT**

You can apply the same concept and use the real regular expression inside:

```
app.get(/\/test\/[^\.]*$/, function (req, res) {
  res.send('catch it without dot');
});

app.get('/test/*', function (req, res) {
  res.send('catch it with dot');
});
```

And you can use parentesis **()** to capture params in 
req.params like //test/([^.]*)$/

Comment: you have an update. I hope I understand your problem, basically you can use a full regular expression, if you use the normal syntax, you have access to very small options. No access for example to ^

Comment: the parsed url is in req.originalUrl

Comment: Yes, I did. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764509/what-is-the-proper-regex-syntax-to-use-with-express-routes

Comment: In this case, you can mark a answer as right, write your answer and mark it as right or close the question or flag as duplicated.

Comment: The main problem here is that I was trying to use regex syntax inside a string rather than using a plain regex expression. Beyond that, the question was about using parameter names with express routes and this answer, while not solving my problem, sufficiently answers the question.

Comment: No worries @toshiomagic, This happened to me in a question and a reply to my self and I marked as valid. I don't feel bad if you do it no worries ;) I told you that mark one as valid because a user can see this question and try to reply and you don't need anymore