# What is the proper regex syntax to use with express routes?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

I'm using regex for express routing and I've hit a roadblock. I have a bunch of tests that get run when a url ending with result is GET. a GET on a string **not ending in** result returns a list of folders and links to tests.

I have a regex that works on normal strings

```
var noresult = new RegExp(/^(?![\w\/:].*result$)/);
var result = new RegExp(/^[\w\/:].*result$/);
```

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to implement these in express. I currently have:

```
router.get('/:testPath(^[\w\/:].*result$)', [function (req, res, next) {
    // run mocha test
    // render page
}
```

for my tests and

```
router.get('/:path(?![\w\/:].*result$)', function (req, res) {
    // build folder/file structure
    // render page
}
```

but neither of these works for any url. I want the testPath and path req params to be in the req.params object.

For example, the following three lines work when strings, but not when urls passed to express:

```
/test/path/to/test
/test/path/to/test/
/test/path/to/testfile/result
```

I've seen examples that both use and do not use the /^ or $/ to begin or end the string in express routing examples. I'm not sure if they belong there or not.

What is the proper way to implement regex in express routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the syntax is pure regex. Who would have known! I'm currently using:

```
router.get(/[\w\/:]*result$/, [function (req, res, next) {
router.get(/^(?![\w\/\:].*result$)/, function (req, res, next) {
```

and it works like a charm. Still haven't figured out how to get variables in there. But it works for now.